# Trouble showing the addition of the fractional parts are a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working on some [released exams](https://math.berkeley.edu/courses/archives/exams/math-113), in particular [this one](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F02_First_Midterm-K.Ribet_.pdf) and I am stuck on 4B.

I know I need to prove three properties to show that it is a group:

1. The operation is associativity
2. There exists an identity
3. There exists an inverse.

I can find a solution for 2 and 3 somewhat easily:

For 2:

Let $x$ be an element belonging to the equivalence class. Then $[x + 0] = [x]$, which implies $[0]$ (not actually zero itself, but zero's equivalence class) is the identity element.

For 3:

Let $[x]$ be an element belonging to the equivalence class. Then $[x + (-x)] = [0]$ which implies $[-x]$ is the inverse of [x].

I am having trouble with the last part, associativity. I'm virtually lost:

Let $x,y$ and $z$ be elements of arbitrary equivalence classes. Then:

$$[[x + y] + z] = ?$$

I don't know what to do from here. Any ideas? Also, when the question states:

> Be sure to check that the operation is well defined.

I don't understand what I am supposed to be looking for. My first though is that there isn't a unique identity or inverse... But the more I stare at the problem, I believe there is.

Comment: Well defined means that if $[x] = [x']$ and $[y] = [y']$, then $[x]+[y] = [x']+[y']$. This says that the addition rule is not dependent upon your choice of representative. Equivalently, it means that if $x\sim x'$ and $y\sim y'$, then $x+y\sim x'+y'$. (The group operation respects the equivalence relation.)

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Ok, I guess that is there to help with the identity element confusion I initially had. That should be simple enough: $x-x' = n$, $y-y' = k$ $x + y - x' - y' = x - x' + y - y' = n + k$. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: I wrote [a detailed example of what it means for an operation to be “well-defined”](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782093/what-are-well-defined-functions/782122#782122) and what goes wrong when it isn't. This might help you understand why we care whether the operation is well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your answer,
$$[[x+y]+z]$$
does not make sense.  To work it out you would have to begin with
$$[x+y]+z\ ,$$
which is a set plus an individual number, which cannot be done.  The associative law states that
$$(\,[x]+[y]\,)+[z]=[x]+(\,[y]+[z]\,)\ :$$
if you carefully use the definition of addition, and make sure you do the steps in the right order, you should find this is not too hard to prove.

---

Re: well-defined, let's start with an example of something which is **not** well defined.  Suppose you try to order your equivalence classes by defining
$$[x]>[y]\quad\hbox{if and only if}\quad x>y\ .$$
Then we have, for example,
$$[0.5]>[0.2]\quad\hbox{and}\quad [0.5]<[1.2]\ .$$
But this does not make sense, because the equivalence class $[1.2]$ is the same as $[0.2]$, so we have said that it is both less than and greater than $[0.5]$.  We say that the order specified here is **not well-defined**: the point is that since $[0.2]=[1.2]$, anything sensible that we say about this class cannot depend on the *specific* numbers $0.2$ or $1.2$.

Looking at addition, we have for example
$$[0.2]+[0.5]=[0.7]\ .$$
If we calculate $[1.2]+[0.5]$ it is really the same sum, so we should get the same answer.  And indeed,
$$[1.2]+[0.5]=[1.7]=[0.7]\ .$$
What you have to prove is that addition always works "properly" in this respect, that is,
$$\hbox{if}\quad [x_1]=[x_2]\ \hbox{and}\ [y_1]=[y_2]\ ,\quad\hbox{then}\quad
  [x_1+y_1]=[x_2+y_2]\ .$$
Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. As for the second part, I talk about it with Cameron. As for the first part, interpreting the operation as you say I should I get: $([x] + [y]) + [z] = [x] + ([y] + [z])$ Which implies: $[x+y] + [z] = [x] + [y+z]$ Which implies: $[(x+y) + z] = [x + (y + z)]$ Which using additions associative-ness gives: $[x+y+z] = [x+y+z]$ Correct?

Comment: Correct except that the logic is backwards, you need to start with $[(x+y)+z]=[x+(y+z)]$ and finish with $([x]+[y])+[z]=[x]+([y]+[z])$.

Comment: Ok thanks! Yeah, I wrote it backward mostly because it is a comment and I wanted to keep it compact, but still illustrate the crux of my point. I have it better written out in my notebook. Thanks!