# Showing the affine transformation is well-defined

Tags: group-theory, functions, finite-groups

Let V be an n-dim vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}.$

$A \in GL\left ( n,\mathbb{F} \right )$ and $v \in V$

Define the affine transformation $t_{A,v}$:

$V\rightarrow V$

$x \mapsto xA+v$

Showing that this map is a bijection from V to V is simple. Indeed, by definition, $t_{A,v}$ is a permutation.
I'd like to show that this map is well-defined but unsure how to do so. 
The link below provides the lemma to do so.

[helpful link from Mathstack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190628/in-group-theory-proofs-what-is-meant-by-well-defined)

With the lemma, I am unsure how to begin. Looking only for **hints**.

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined? There is no choice involved in the definition which might change the value of the function.

Comment: It means $t_{A,v}=t_{A',v'}$. @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: @Mathematicing It's still not clear what you mean. Do you mean that you want to show that $t_{A, v} = t_{A', v'}$ implies that $(A, v) = (A', v')$? This says that map $(A, v) \mapsto t_{A, v}$ is injective. Or do you want that the map is surjective (that is, that every affine map can be written this way)? Both?

Comment: Hi @Travis 
I apologise for the vagary of my question.
On my lecture slides, it says that if $A\neq A'$ and $v\neq v'$ then $t_{A,v}\neq t_{A',v'}$ and this can be verified.
So my interpretation of the wording is that the map can be checked if it is well-defined.

Comment: As an aside, since $t_{A,v}$ is a permutation, is there a reason for which the notation is written as $(x)^{t_{A,v}}$ rather than as $(x)t_{A,v}$? The exponential notation in the former is usually used to denote group action as I am aware.

Comment: @Travis I think your former question is what I am looking for since it fits the  contraposition of what is written on my lecture slides.

Comment: No, what you wrote there means that the map is injective, not that it is well-defined (it is trivially well-defined).

Comment: What Tobias said---well-definedness is something completely separate that isn't an issue here. Note that injectivity of this map is the same thing as *faithfulness* of the group action. (By the way, my previous comment should say "...every *invertible* affine map can be written this way...".)

Comment: As for the notation, I'd find the superscript notation probably unwieldy in this case, and the notation $(x) t_{A, v}$ simply misleading, because the action $x \mapsto A x + v$ is a left action, not a right one.

Comment: @Travis I have more question pertaining to this question. Do I construct a thread?

Comment: If it's a distinct question from this yes, in short, yes.